# How can i edit an array from another part subProgram

Tags: java, arrays

Before someone says 'We're not solving your homework, ask your teacher' I only get programming on a Wednesday and this is not homework. It's an extra task that i asked for

Anyways i'm trying to create a program that i can Input a game's name and price then display the titles of all the games(which are in an array) and then another option to display the total price of all games

The issue i'm having is that i can't add to the array(Hard to explain so here's my code )

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
```

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Java {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Java.mainMenu();
}
public static void mainMenu() {

    // ArrayList titleArray
    // PrimitiveArray priceArray
    int choice = 0;
    String again = "";
    String[] gameTitle = new String[0];

    Scanner user_input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("    Main Menu");
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("1) Enter Game Details");
    System.out.println("2) Display Titles in Order");
    System.out.println("3) Display Total Price");
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("Choice : ");
    choice = user_input.nextInt();

    if (choice ==1){

        gameDetails(gameTitle);

    } else if (choice ==2) {
        displayTitles(gameTitle);
    } else if (choice ==3) {

    }

}
public static void displayTitles(String[] gameTitle) {
    // Choice 2

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(gameTitle));

}
public static void gameDetails(String[] gameTitle) {
    //Choice 1

    String addGameTitle;
    double addGamePrice;
    Scanner user_input = new Scanner(System.in);


    System.out.println("Enter the game Title : ");
    addGameTitle = user_input.next();
    Java.mainMenu();
}
```

}

So i run this and put 1 in, it asks me for the Title of the game i enter it but it doesn't get added to the array? Is it because of the way that i am Passing the array?

Comment: Which line do you think is adding to your (empty!) array?

Comment: Please read and try this first: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: shmosel that's what i'm trying to figure out. I've tried multiple different ways of adding to an array but none seem to work. The one is just tried was gameTitle.add(addGameTitle); just above the very last Java.mainMenu();

Comment: larsgrefer thanks for that website but i already have my test table, specifications, psuedocode etc ready but it's just adding to an Array i'm struggling with because this is the first official programming language i'm learning

Answer (score 0):

try doing an array list!

```
List<array length> <name> = new ArrayList<array length>
<arrayname>.add(<location in array>) = <something>
<arrayname>.add(<location in array>) = <something>
```

Unfortunately, you will need to have a set length of the array beforehand, which means you can't add to it after you have filled the capacity of the array.

hope this helps!

(Note: I'm relatively new to java myself so I could be forgetting something, or misremembering.)

Comment: Is there any way to add to this array without specifying the location? Because i don't know how many times the user might enter a game,

Comment: @Thom What i ment was the location being read. (example: an array with values 1,2,3 each contained in a new part of the array. location 0 has value 1, location 1 has two, and location 2 has 3. )values contained would be defined by you, of course. again, i could be misremembering.